# How to get body data in logs for each request in K6

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, quality-assurance, test-tools, k6

I would like to know: how can I get the body data in response to each request in K6?

I tried using `console.log(response.body)`, but it did not provide a solution for it. Either it gives a response in binary or displays nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use your the object from your request.

For example

```js
let res = http.post(url, payload,params);
console.log(res.body);
```

I've found that with some json, nulls have caused issues.  In those cases I've used stringify to clean it up before printing.

```js
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, "  "));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
const res = http.get(`${url}/v1/`)
check(res, {
  'is status 200': (r) => r.status === 200
})
console.log(res.body)
```